# Using Laplace Transformation Calculate the given integral

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

The question says that I should calculate the following integral using Laplace transformation.
[image]

I know the formula for the Laplace transform: [image]

I've also added the -st to -x since the base is **e**

[image]

I am not sure how I would solve this, the ratio (sin(x))^2/x should be done with Taylor's expansion since this can't be solved with known integrals method..

**Note:** the (sin(x))^2/x ratio is not in the exponent (the power) it's rather in the exp line (multiplication)...

Comment: Write $sin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos(2x)$, split the integrals and find what $F(1)$ of your integrals equals using a [Laplace table](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that we have

$$F(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\,dx$$

Therefore, we can write

$$\begin{align}
F'(s)&=-\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\sin^2(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\left(1-\cos(2x)\right)\,dx \tag 1
\end{align}$$

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> Recall that the Laplace Transforms of $1$ and $\cos(ax)$ are $\frac1s$ and $\frac{s}{s^2+a^2}$, respectively.  Using this in $(1)$ reveals $$F'(s)=-\frac12\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{s}{s^2+4}\right)\tag 2$$Integrating $(2)$ and using the fact that $\lim_{s\to \infty }F(s)=0$ yields $$F(s)=\frac14 \log\left(1+\frac{4}{s^2}\right)$$from which we find $$F(1)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\,dx=\frac14 \log(5)$$And we are done!

Comment: I'll do my best..

Comment: Tnx for everything, I found the solution, although I'm a programmer I just never find time to learn latex so I struggle with images...

Comment: You're welcome! My pleasure. -Mark

Comment: I already did at the beginning (first vote I believe)

Comment: @wesewx Thank you!!  Much appreciated. -Mark